# Do I name this class property name right?

Tags: c#

I'm working with `enum` and I'm not sure that I've named them with the right names.

It looks like:

```
public class VietNam
{
    public enum Regions
    {
        [Display(Name = "Khu vực miền Trung")]
        Central = 0,
        [Display(Name = "Khu vực miền Bắc")]
        North = 1,
        [Display(Name = "Khu vực miền Nam")]
        South = 2
    }

    public enum CentralCities
    {
        [Display(Name = "Đà Nẵng")]
        TPDN = 0,
        [Display(Name = "Bình Định")]
        BD = 1,
        // ...
    }

    public enum NorthCities
    {
        [Display(Name = "Hà Nội")]
        TPHN = 0,
        [Display(Name = "Hải Phòng")]
        HP = 1,
        // ...
    }

    public enum SouthCities
    {
        [Display(Name = "Hồ Chí Minh")]
        TPHCM = 0,
        [Display(Name = "Cần Thơ")]
        CT = 1,
        // ...
    }
}
```

And:

```
public sealed class SearchEngine : ISearchEngine
{
    public IEnumerable<Post> FindPostsByRegion(VietNam.Regions region)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Post> FindPostsByCity(VietNam.CentralCities city)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Post> FindPostsByCity(VietNam.NorthCities city)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Post> FindPostsByCity(VietNam.SouthCities city)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

My troubles:

```
public enum Regions {}
```

Because this property contains more than 1 member, so the name should be `Regions` instead of `Region`. I'm using same concept to `CentralCities`, `NorthCities` and `SouthCities` instead of `CentralCity`, `NorthCity` and `SouthCity`.

Everything looks good until I use it:

```
public IEnumerable<Post> FindPostsByRegion(VietNam.Regions region) {}
```

So, how can a `region` be an instance of `Regions`? `region` just contains 1 region name (North, Central or South). Then, if I rename it (changing from `region` to `regions`), the concept looks okay (`regions` is an instance of `Regions`) but it just contains only 1 region name. Something goes wrong.

Same to the cities. `CentralCities` contains more than 1 city, so the name should be followed by `ies`. So, what's happen if I just want exactly 1 city name? Like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Post> FindPostsByCity(VietNam.CentralCities city) {}
```

`city` is an instance of `cities` (`CentralCities`)?

For now, I haven't thought other names to change them all yet. My question is: Is that okay if I still use the name like that?

I hope my question is clearly. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well. [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-classes-structs-and-interfaces#naming-enumerations) says to use singular type names for enumerations.

Below quote taken from Microsoft site

> > Naming Enumerations Names of enumeration types (also called enums) in general should follow the standard type-naming rules (PascalCasing,
> >     etc.). However, there are additional guidelines that apply
> >     specifically to enums.
>
> ✓ DO use a singular type name for an enumeration unless its values are
>   bit fields.
>
> ✓ DO use a plural type name for an enumeration with bit fields as
>   values, also called flags enum.
>
> X DO NOT use an "Enum" suffix in enum type names.
>
> X DO NOT use "Flag" or "Flags" suffixes in enum type names.
>
> X DO NOT use a prefix on enumeration value names (e.g., "ad" for ADO
>   enums, "rtf" for rich text enums, etc.).

Agreed that you have different enum values within that enum. But at the end, you are not going to use all of them at the same time. But you will use only one enum value among the all of them.

*So may be in my opinion, change the enum names to singular. Again its my opinion*

Answer (score 0):

In general, enum names should be singular, but it is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed to use singular names for enumerations. (Use plural names for sequences and other containers.) It just sounds better that way.

Aside: since the `NorthCities`, `SouthCities` and `CentralCities` are all just... cities, it will be easier to just make a single enumeration for all of them. After all, the `FindPostsByCity` will work the same way regardless. If you need to keep track of what city is in which region, then create data that explicitly maps that out: a `Dictionary<VietNam.City, VietNam.Region>`, and/or `Dictionary<VietNam.Region, List<VietNam.City>>`.

Comment: Thank you! But I don't think this case will work: `Dictionary<VietNam.City, VietNam.Region>`. Because `Region` is not a definition of `City`.

Comment: The key and value types do not need to be related.